# Single enumeration with multiple filters

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following contrived example:

```
public bool NumberOfEvensEqualsNumberOfOdds(IEnumerable<int> numbers) {
    var numberOfEvens = numbers.Count(x => x % 2 == 0);
    var numberOfOdds = numbers.Count(x => x % 2 != 0);

    return numberOfEvens == numberOfOdds;
}
```

This works but requires multiple enumerations of the collection.

Is it possible to re-write this to use a single linq expression that enumerates the collection once.

NOTE: I'm trying to solve the general case of comparing counts with two filters so try and ignore the fact that the sample is about odd and even numbers.

I have included a sample [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6dq2DY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit cryptic at first glance, but only iterates through the collection once.

```
Func<int, bool> isEven = n => n % 2 == 0;
Func<int, bool> isFive = n => n == 5;
int diff = numbers.Aggregate(0, (sum, next) => isEven(next) ? sum + 1 : isFive(next) ? sum - 1 : sum);
```

For each item in the collection, it checks the two conditions.  If the first condition applies, it adds one to the aggregate variable; if the second applies, it subtracts one.  The end result is the difference between the number of items that meet the first criteria and the number of items that meet the second.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it was the one I ultimately used and was the simplest, however for other scenarios see Michael Liu's answer. I wish I could accept them both

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var groupedByCondition =
    = numbers.GroupBy(x => x % 2 == 0)
             .Select(x => new { Result = x.Key, Count = g.Count() })
             .ToArray();

return groupedByCondition.Length == 2
    && groupedByCondition[0].Count == groupedBycondition[1].Count;
```

Comment: I should have explained myself better. What if I wanted to know if the numbers of 2's equals the number of 7's? Your solution relies on one condition being the inverse of the other.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two **disjoint** filters (that is, an item can't simultaneously satisfy both filters), then BJ Myer's answer may be as simple and efficient as you can get.

If you have two **not-necessarily disjoint** filters, then you can use the following slight variation which always evaluates both filters for every item:

```
public static bool NumberOfEvensEqualsNumberOfOdds(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    // Compute
    //   numbers.Count(x => x % 2 == 0)       - numbers.Count(x => x % 2 != 0)
    // or equivalently,
    //   numbers.Sum(x => x % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0) - numbers.Sum(x => x % 2 != 0 ? 1 : 0)
    int sum = numbers.Sum(x =>
        (x % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0) -
        (x % 2 != 0 ? 1 : 0));
    return sum == 0;
}
```

If you have an **arbitrary number of not-necessarily disjoint** filters, then you can use the following generic method:

```
public static bool HasEqualSizeSubsets<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> items, params Func<T, bool>[] filters)
{
    var indexedFilters = filters
        .Select((filter, index) => new { Filter = filter, Index = index })
        .ToArray(); // to avoid repeated object allocations later
    IEnumerable<int> subsetSizes = items
        .SelectMany(item => indexedFilters
            .Where(indexedFilter => indexedFilter.Filter(item))
            .Select(indexedFilter => indexedFilter.Index))
        .GroupBy(index => index)
        .Select(grouping => grouping.Count());
    return subsetSizes.Distinct().Count() == 1;
}
```

HasEqualSizeSubsets looks complicated, but the basic idea is straightforward:

- First, we get the array index of each filter passed in the `filters` array parameter.
- Then, for each `item` in `items`, we get the index of *each* filter that the `item` satisfies. (For example, if the `item` satisfies just the first filter, we output a "0". If the `item` satisfies the first two filters, we output "0" and "1".) The result of the SelectMany call is a sequence of filter indexes.
- Next, we count the number of times each index appears. The result of the GroupBy and Select calls is a sequence of subset sizes.
- Finally, we check whether all the subset sizes are the same unique value.

HasEqualSizeSubsets could be used like this:

```
public static bool NumberOfEvensEqualsNumberOfOdds(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    return HasEqualSizeSubsets(numbers, x => x % 2 == 0, x => x % 2 != 0);
}
```

Comment: Great solutions here.  Kudos for describing the disjoint/non-disjoint requirements for each.

Answer (score 1):

You code do it this way using `.Aggregate`:

```
public bool NumberOfEvensEqualsNumberOfOdds(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    var result =
        numbers
            .Aggregate(
                new { evens = 0, odds = 0 },
                (a, x) =>
                {
                    a = x % 2 == 0
                        ? new { evens = a.evens + 1, a.odds }
                        : a;
                    a = x % 2 != 0 
                        ? new { a.evens, odds = a.odds + 1 }
                        : a;
                    return a;
                });

    return result.evens == result.odds;
}
```

The logic could be updated to compute and number of different projections from the source numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to you check two different conditions and loop it only one time.
you can use foreach loop and have your own logic inside

```
public static bool NumberOfEvensEqualsNumberOfOdds(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
{
    int evenCount = 0;
    int oddCount = 0;

    foreach (var item in numbers)
    {
        if (item % 2 == 0)
            evenCount++;
        else if (item % 2 != 0)
            oddCount++;  
    }

    return evenCount == oddCount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering if it was possible to express this same logic as a linq statement